# Способ словообразования "белорус"

Tags: словообразование

Задумался, каким образом образовалось слово "белорус" и от какого слова ("Белая Русь", "Белоруссия" или "Белорусь")? В частности, интересует вопрос, почему исчезла мягкость "с" на конце слова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Марк Из, образование понятно. Вам, как историку, наверное попадалось историческое деление древней Руси на белых, червонных и черных ***русов*** или "рос(с)ов". Именно так звучали названия жителей русских земель у европейских географов и историков (не буду утверждать про автохоронимы, т.е. самоназвания, но, вроде, и они имели место). Русь - место, где живут *русы*.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C

Мягкости там нет, оно появляется только в топониме.
Это "цветовое" разделение было разным у западных европейцев и византийцев, но и те и другие население этих земель называли "русами"/"росами".
Подробности, думаю, вы лучше меня найдете.

Так что белорус = белый+рус, "Руси" там напрямую нет.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, сначала образовались слова "рус", "белорус"?

Из статьи http://www.my-works.org/text_103182.html (не знаю, насколько достоверным является источник).

"Слово «рус» чрезвычайно древнее. Русы — это неискажённое самоназвание современного русского народа, в который входят великорусы (русские), малорусы (украинцы), белорусы, сибиряки, поморы и казаки".

О чередовании мягкого и твердого согласного: Россия — росс (русский, россиянин). "Гром победы раздавайся! Веселися, храбрый Росс!" Чередование, возможно, связано с тем, что фактически мягкий согласный не встречается при названии лиц мужского пола по национальности.

Comment: Из приведённого вами источника, - "Люди, считающие себя этнически русскими, могут проговорить эту фразу [*Я рус*] несколько раз вслух, и, если вы действительно русские, то почувствуете некую внутреннюю вибрацию, дрожь, покалывания в затылке или по всему телу или мурашки". Тут вроде не нужно быть специалистом, чтобы понимать, что источник доверия не заслуживает.

Comment: Текст, конечно, странный, но можно предположить, что сначала появилось название народности "белорус", а от него образовалось название страны (в разных вариантах)?

Answer (score 0):

> > Задумался каким образом образовалось слово "белорус" и от какого слова (Белая Русь", "Белоруссия" или "Белорусь")? В частности интересует вопрос почему исчезла мягкость "с" на конце слова.

Люди, это не настоящий Марк Из. Настоящий с пунктуацией вроде бы дружил...

Comment: Никогда с пунктуацией не дружил, если вас это смущает, можете исправить ошибки, рейтинг вам вроде позволяет. В любом случае подобные замечания следует оставлять в комментариях, а не в ответе.